# "Page Not Found" after editing an answer from a mobile device on "Full Site"

Tags: bug, status-completed, answers, edits, mobile-web

I have found, when editing my answers via my iPhone on SO in the Full Site (*Non*-"Mobile"  ) version, that after clicking "Save Edits" I am taken to the "Page Not Found" error page and my edits are not applied to the answer.

I have also tested this using Chrome with `open -a Google\ Chrome.app --args '--user-agent="Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU like Mac OS X; en) AppleWebKit/420+ (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/3.0 Mobile/1A543a Safari/419.3'` but I do not get the same "Page Not Found".

It works just fine when faking the user-agent via a normal browser, but it happens 100% of the time from my actual iPhone.

Seems this can happen on a Blackberry as well.

Comment: I had this happen to me yesterday from my BlackBerry, when attempting to edit a question. So the problem is more general.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mobile device on full-site scenario had a path HTML/JavaScript combo that was happening, resulting in the edit `<form>` being a GET rather than the required POST.  Since the route that goes to only listens for a POST, you got a 404.

This will be fixed in the next build.